# How can I make a dictionary / collections.counter that takesz into account the index in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, collections, counter

I am aware of dictionaries and collection.Counters in Python.
My question is how can I make one that takes index of the string into account?
For example for this string: aaabaaa
I would like to make a tuples that contain each string in progression, keeping track of the count going left to right and resetting the count once a new alphanumeric is found.
For example, I like to see this output:
 [('a', 3), ('b', 1), ('a', 3)]

Any idea how to use the dictionary / Counter/ or is there some other data structure built into Python I can use?

Regards

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! It will be great if you can also include the code snippet that you have tried, results or expected results to help people understand your question.

Comment: you can't map multiple things to the same key in a dictionary.  I suppose that there are the concepts of mutli-dicts in some languages which you could spoof in python using a `defaultdict(list)` or something ... Anyway, in this case, I think maybe you're better off using `itertools`.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

m = [(k, sum(1 for _ in v)) for k, v in groupby('aaabaaa')]

print(m)
```

**Output**

```
[('a', 3), ('b', 1), ('a', 3)]
```

**Explanation**

The groupby function makes an iterator that returns consecutive keys and groups from the iterable, in this case `'aaabaaa'`. The key `k` is the value identifying of the group, `['a', 'b', 'a']`. The `sum(1 for _ in v)` count the amount of elements in the group.

Comment: Thx for your reply, but I copied your code into my Python 3 environment and am getting this error:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
How would I assign it to a variable, could I just do something like this:
m = []
m = [(k, sum(1 for _ in v)) for k, v in groupby('aaabaaa')]

That above is also giving me an error

Comment: @fynx Updated the answer to include a variable assignment! Just remove `m = []`

Comment: @fynx If my answer helped to solve your problem, please consider [marking it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/195035). That's the customary way of indicating that your question is "resolved" and thanking the person who helped you.

Comment: Oh thx for telling me about the accepted thing, I did not know about it.  I am a newb